# Is there a way to prevent aliases from getting reset upon deployment?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have set up a CloudFront distribution, using serverless, with a couple of default aliases. The aliases may be updated outside the `serverless.yaml` configuration scope. Is it possible to prevent aliases from being reset with the defaults upon each deployment when something changes in terms of distribution configuration?

If nothing changes in terms of the distribution configuration, nothing is reset with the defaults. I could probably try and remove the aliases after the first deployment to make sure nothing is updated through configuration from then on but that's not an ideal way to work configurations.

```
# serverless.yaml
...
resources:
  Resources:
    myLovelyDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Aliases:
            - alias1
            - alias2
...
```

Initially, I was hoping that the Aliases would remain unchanged on each deployment, despite any update outside the `serverless.yaml` configuration scope. Since that's not the case, is there a way to force a merge or prevent any reset if the distribution is only being updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible as you described it. However, I do have an idea for you to consider, but first a warning...

I must remind you what you seem to already know: It is a generally unwise to update your configuration using multiple tools and methods. Choose only one, and stick with it.

Now to my idea: When faced with these types of challenges I like to use a key/value store to "glue" multiple tools/methods together. Most people use AWS Parameter Store, which is in the Systems Manager area.

```
# serverless.yaml
...
resources:
  Resources:
    myLovelyDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Aliases: [${ssm:/path/to/this/service/CloudFront/Aliases}] 
...
```

Now, this process that you mentioned is out-of-scope of `serverless.yaml`, can be updated with the awscli `aws ssm put-parameter --parameter-name  /path/to/this/service/CloudFront/Aliases --value alias1,alias2,alias3`or AWS Console by a human person.